Redis timeout issue in ASP.NET Core
I have an ASP.NET Core application and when setting and retrieving values from Redis cache, I am facing timeout issues. I see that the CPU load is good and memory usage is around 260 MB. This issue happens on prod and not in development.
I need to know if it would be good to have thread to increase minimum worker process, or any other solution would be fine.
Code:
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, 20)

Error setting:

Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=1720KiB, 6016ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=SETEX, next: SETEX data:list:8756789:020250107_09_30_00:S00, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 86, last-in: 11688, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 121831, serverEndpoint: xxxxx, conn-sec: 74643,13, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: xxxxxx(Redis-v2.8.0.27420), IOCP: (Busy=6,Free=994,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=16,Free=32751,Min=4,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=34,QueuedItems=4,CompletedItems=7022584,Timers=156), v: 2.8.0.27420

Error get

Timeout awaiting response (outbound=3588KiB, inbound=499KiB, 5438ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=EXISTS, next: GET data:list:2345876:020241220_14_00_00:S00, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 54330, last-in: 1880304, cur-in: 1793806, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 128364, serverEndpoint: xxxx, conn-sec: 76871,54, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: xxxxx(Redis-v2.8.0.27420), IOCP: (Busy=4,Free=996,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=15,Free=32752,Min=4,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=59,QueuedItems=6,CompletedItems=7238691,Timers=154), v: 2.8.0.27420


I don't think changing the threads will assist here; based on qu and qs, unless I'm misreading it, this looks like there's only one command in-flight; I'm not seeing an in-pipe or out-pipe, which suggests that there's no data outstanding - so overall, my hunch here is that this is a server-side stall. Have you checked SLOWLOG GET on the server to see if there are any long-running operations reported? Also: is it possible that this is bandwidth/latency related, i.e. "I sent 40 GiB to a server on the other side of the planet"

@MarcGravell Can you please let me know how we can enable slowlog for redis in azure portal
